# "Swivel plane" tangent vector in Séquin circle spline

Tags: vectors, interpolation, spline

I'm trying to implement the circle spline scheme described [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cad.2004.06.009). I feel like I have a solid working understanding of the procedure, but I'm generally pretty rusty when it comes to geometry. A big sticking point is in section 3.2 (at the top of page 205), where a function for a tangent vector, $t(u)$, is described. It's "found by a swivel operation" in a plane and drawn at a point. I've tried to look up what "swivel operation" means to no avail; my current assumption is that it means rotating a vector around an axis by an angle.

However, that assumption might be wrong, because my current implementation just sweeps a line between each pair of points, instead of the smooth circle-like curve it should produce. Even if the assumption is correct, I don't see where the paper explains which vector should be rotated to begin with (I've tried $\mathbf{b}$ and $t_i$, but neither seemed to make a difference).

I think I'm approaching $t(u)$ wrong, so I'll try to start over here. What is the procedure they are describing to find $t(u)$?

Comment: Instead of making people dig through an over 200-page off-site paper, you should include all of the relevant context in your question.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure about the etiquette for papers. (What's linked isn't actually 200 pages long, since it's the paper removed from the journal without changing the page numbering, but your point still stands.) My concern is that it's closed access - are there any issues with rights if I post an excerpt here? If not, I'll gladly edit the question with context